# Dovecot copy user emails

Tags: dovecot

I have to create new accounts for certain users, copy all their mailing to their new account and then disable the old one (so not simply renaming email users).

Eg:

user1@corp.com to usernewname1@corp.com

I did add usernewname1 and tried a simple cp -R on the vmail folder of the old user, it's not working. The rights on the files are ok but when I login with usernewname1 I don't see any emails in any folders.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [doveadm-import](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Import) for that, here's the syntax:

```
doveadm [-Dv] import [-S socket_path] [-s] -u user source_location dest_parent search_query
```

As you haven't provided details on your setup, I can't give a more detailed information.